# How can I create a REG_MULTI_SZ key through Group Policy?

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

I'm trying to add an entry to registry via Group Policy, but I can only seem to create either a `REG_SZ` or `REG_DWORD` value. If I insert the value as a `REG_SZ` key then it isn't picked up / processed as it needs to be a multi string key. The code I'm using in the ADM template is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
CATEGORY "PCI-DSS Compliance"
KEYNAME "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\"

 POLICY "Enable Strong Password Filtering"
  PART "Value" EDITTEXT
  VALUENAME "notification packages"
  END PART
 END POLICY

END CATEGORY
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any syntax to create a `REG_Multi_SZ` key through an ADM template?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

They are only supported using admx's, So unless your going to create a policy for 2008,,

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd367852(WS.10).aspx